# How can I load a specific component from an HTML template in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I added VueJS to my Django project using webpack loader. Vue works, but i'm very new to it so i'm struggling to understand the structure.

I have the following template:

**django_template.html**: this is where i'm loading the Vue app

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

{% block content %}
    
<div id="app">
    <app></app>
</div>
                      
{% render_bundle 'chunk-vendors' %}
{% render_bundle 'chart' %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now there is my Vue app where i have two basic components, one is **testComponent1.vue**

```
<template><h1>This is the test component one</h1></template>
```

and another is  **testComponent2.vue**:

```
<template><h1>This is the test component two</h1></template>
```

Then i have **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <testComponent1></testComponent1>
    <testComponent2></testComponent2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import testComponent1 from "./components/testComponent1";
import testComponent2 from "./components/testComponent2";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    'testComponent1': testComponent1,
    'testComponent2': testComponent2,
  },
};

</script>
```

And finally **main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import axios from 'axios'

import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
}).$mount("#app");
```

Now my question is:

How do i call only a specific component and not all of them? The code i provided will load all the components of the vue app, but since i'm using Vue with Django, on a certain HTML page i will want some component, on another page i'll need another component. Any kind of advice is appreciated!

Comment: How does Django inform your VueJS app which component to load?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: Vue is not really suitable to render classic Django pages/routes. Vue is a framework to build a [single page app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application); Django serves the entire Vue app once, then typically only exchanges pure data with the Vue app running in the browser. SEO URLs can be simulated using Vue's [router package](https://router.vuejs.org/), but in general, whether a component is displayed or not is implemented using conditional rendering, where the (ever-changing) state of your app determines which components appear as part of the DOM and which ones are removed.

Comment: Unless you have a very good understanding of classical server-side rendering vs. SPA rendering, I suggest sticking to either Django templates or using Vue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I disagree about Vue being suitable only for SPA, i'm pretty sure they explicitly said Vue can be used for SSR apps or progressive web apps too. This is what webpack-loader was made for

Comment: A django+vue solution does exist, again it's mentioned by Vue themselves that the framework is not exclusive for SPA, it's perfectly fine and possible to combine them without losing the benefits of both, there is a lot of material about that, i suggest checking out https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218588/using-vue-with-django

Comment: Not to mention that Vue can be used with Django just by adding it's CDN on the HTML page, and that's another perfectly fine way to do it, according to Vue's docs

Comment: Yes, like I said: taken at face value, yes, you can serve a bunch of Vue apps with Django routes (which I think is nonsense unless you limit yourself to a few very basic Vue compoents, regardless of a random medium article claiming otherwise). Your question does not read like you were aware of this when you asked it, so what exactly are we even arguing about here? If you have all the resources and know better what works and what doesn't, what are you even doing here...?

Comment: Just include your Vue app in all your Django templates, grab `location.href` and display components accordingly using conditional rendering.

Comment: My question is not about if i should or should not use Vue with Django, it is about Vue's apps structure. I'm new to Vue and i had troubles with that, my problem was not with using Vue with Django. I think it's pretty clear

Comment: What i don't understand is why did this turn into an argument on whether i should or should not use Vue with Django when the question is pretty clearly about Vue's components?

Comment: It's because the question sounded to me like you had no concept of what an SPA is or how it works, so I tried to dissuade you, a person who is "very new to it" from going down a route that is at best maybe useful once you have mastered Vue. You can always revisit using Django + Vue in combination on the frontend once you have the basics down, right? Your actual question was answered by Adam's comment, so I gave additional info regarding the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousands of options you can go with.
The easiest one if you want just disable them just use `if/else` statement:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

`Vue is awesome!

Oh no `

Or you can go with dynamic components:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

```
<component v-bind:is="currentComponent"></component>
```

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => { currentComponent: 'testComponent1' }
  components: {
    'testComponent1': testComponent1,
    'testComponent2': testComponent2,
  },
};
```